# How to delete table rows in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i want to delete a table row from my database with MySQL and PHP. I have searched on the internet and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have the feeling I'm close.

If I go over the delete link there is a link showing with the ID number of the row to delete. But if I click it, it isn't working.

This is my code for admin.php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['E2ingelogd'])) {
        header("location:../../index.php");
    }

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Kan niet inloggen");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);





        if(isset($_POST['team'])){
            $team = $_POST['team'];
            $ID = $_POST['id'];         

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e2teams WHERE Team='$team' and ID='$ID'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username
                echo "$team bestaat al!";
            }
            else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO e2teams (Team) VALUES ('$team')");
                header("location:e2admin.php");
            }
    }

    mysql_close();
?>

<html><head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo"><img height="140" src="../images/boyslogo.png"> </div>
                <div class="titelpagina">Vroomshoopse Boys E2 admin panel</div>
                <div class="uitloggen"><a href="../../logout.php">Uitloggen</a></div>
            </div>
      <div class="content">
                <div class="teamstoevoegenvak">
                    <div class="titelbalk">
                        <h1>Voeg teams toe</h1>

                            <form style="border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px"; action="e2admin.php" method="POST">
                                <input width="400" maxlength="400" type="text" name="team" placeholder="Team naam" /><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" />
                            </form></div>
                 </div>
                    <div clas="toegevoegdeteamsvak">
                    <div class="titelbalktoege">
                        <h1>Toegevoegde teams</h1>
                    </div>
                   <div class="deteams">
                    <?php
                        $table = "e2teams";
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM e2teams";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbhandle);
                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            $team = array();
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                echo "<table><tr><td class='styled-td'>";
                                echo $row['Team']. '</td><td></td><td><a href="edit.php?edit='.$row['ID'].'">Bewerk</a></td><td><a href="delete.php?del='.$row['ID'].'">Delete<br>';
                                echo "</td></tr></table>";
                                $team = $row['Team'];
                            }
                        }
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>

      </div>
      <div id="volgendewedstrijd">      <form action="" method="post">
<select name="dropdown">
<?php
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo '<option value="">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
</form></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The piece of code where the delete is, is this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                $team = array();
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                    echo "<table><tr><td class='styled-td'>";
                                    echo $row['Team']. '</td><td></td><td><a href="edit.php?edit='.$row['ID'].'">Bewerk</a></td><td><a href="delete.php?del='.$row['ID'].'">Delete<br>';
                                    echo "</td></tr></table>";
                                    $team = $row['Team'];
                                }
                            }
                            mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
                        ?>
```

And this is my delete.php:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['E2ingelogd'])) {
        header("location:../../index.php");
    }

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = $_GET[id]");
    echo "Team is deleted";
    header('location: e2admin.php');
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = $_GET[id]");
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = ".$_GET['del']."");
```

Because of:

```
<a href="del.php?del='.$row['ID'].'"> //the get var name is: del
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using del as a param in the link

```
<a href="delete.php?del='.$row['ID'].'">Delete<br>
```

This needs to be closed as

```
<a href="delete.php?del='.$row['ID'].'">Delete</a><br>
```

And in the delete script you need to get it as

```
$id = (int)$_GET["del"];
```

and use in the query as

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = $id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a variable inside a array between quotes:

Change the following line

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = $_GET[id]");
```

to

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = " . $_GET['id']);
```

This is a security risk and you are acceptable to SQL injections. Please google: "php sql injections".

Comment: It is still not working. Can it be that my link is not right? : _<a href="delete.php?del='.$row['ID'].'">Delete</a>_

Comment: Match the parameter in the link, thus $_GET['del'].